# XPath Java obtaining list with no repeating names

Tags: java, xpath

i'm learning to parse XML files and using XPath to do querys. I don't know how to list all the Names but i don't want them repeated. Is there any option or should i do it manually?

```
<Return>
  <ReturnData>
    <Person>
      <Name>Samuel</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Samuel</Name>
    </Person>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: You can use Set. That avoids duplicates automatically.  More you can reasd about set [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 and higher, use `distinct-values(//Name)`.

Java's built-in XPath processor only supports XPath 1.0, in which this query is surprisingly difficult, but there are third-party Java libraries supporting XPath 2.0, 3.0, and 3.1, notably Saxon. Saxon-HE is open source, see http://saxon.sf.net/.